# How can i use InteractiveViewer widget on linux with touch screen?

Tags: linux, flutter, zooming, interactive, flutter-linux

I am trying to use **InteractiveViewer** widget to make zoom to image .
It's working for phones but i want to use it for **linux application** but the zoom not working for gestures with two fingers?
Any one have a suggestions or solutions ?

My code like this:

```
InteractiveViewer(
  child: Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: GestureDetector(

      child: Image.network(
        "image link here",
        scale: 1.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```